# Trying to execute a part of my program everytime a key is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard

I am using Tkinter for the first time and I am having some trouble. I want to check for a key-combination (Ctrl + the minus key on the numpad). I tried using the root.bind function but I just can't get the key combination to work. When I typed in 
`root.bind("<Control_L-->" lambda x: print("Hello World"))` 
It printed out Hello World whenever I pressed Ctrl and didn't care wether I was pressing the minus key or not. Also when I type in just - without the <Control_L> it works both for when I press minus on the keyboard and the numpad which I would like to avoid if possible. 
Can anybody tell me, what to put in there so I get it to work only when I press left Ctrl and minus on the Numpad? 
Another thing giving me trouble is the fact that it only checks for key presses when I am inside of the gui. If I'm inside of my browser and just have the gui open on my second monitor and press the keys it doesn't register it but I need it to work even when the app is not focused or minimized. Does anybody know how I could do that? I know about the keyboard module but when I try to use it before the root.mainloop() the gui doesn't work or if I put it after it the code checking for the key doesn't work. 
`if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl + -"): print("Hello World")`

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to the wrong key symbol - you want `Control` and `minus`

```
root.bind("<Control-minus>" lambda x: print("Hello World"))
```